# I'd like to introduce myself to someone by using "a good side of me" and "a weak side of me"

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd like to introduce myself to someone by using "a good side of me" and "a weak side of me". The reason I do this is that I know I can use "an another side of Korean drinking culture" when I need to bring up another sub topic of something that I'm currently discussing. So, am I right to do this?

> I'm more of a person who enjoys spending time by myself than a person who likes to spend time with others. And **a good side of me is that** I don't have many friends but I do care about my close friends more than anyone does their friends. And **a weak side of me is that** I feel jealousy a lot and that makes my relationship with my girlfriend worse than it would otherwise be.

Answer (score 2):

> I know I can use "*an another side of Korean drinking culture" . . .

No, you should un-know that. *An* doesn't go with *another*. It should rather be *another side of Korean drinking culture*, which would need additional polishing depending on what that phrase is supposed to mean in your context.

---

Why over-complicate stuff? You can just say

> One good thing about me is my . . .

Or

> The best thing about me is that I . . .

Alternatively, you could use

> One of my most prominent **upsides**/**downsides** is . . .
>
> One of my **strengths**/**weaknesses** is . . .

Or other constructions, such as:

### For strengths:

> I'm **gifted** in the sense that I . . .
>
> I **have a gift** for [VERB]ing . . .
>
> My **forte** is . . .
>
> I have an outstanding talent . . .

### For weak spots:

> I'm **incapable** of [VERB]ing . . . (clearly).
>
> I have **an Achilles heel** about [VERB]ing . . .
>
> The **chink** in my **armor** is that I . . .

---

> And a weak side of me is that I feel *jealousy a lot and that makes . . .

*Jealousy* is a noun. Don't forget that you need an adjective there. Therefore, use *jealous*, or *envious*, but not **jealousy*, **envy* etc.